# Paradigms and mindsets?

Tags: paradigms

Do people that do functional programming have a certain mindset or people that do pure-oop. Like I just want to know how you guys see programming. This is in no way a technical question but more of a opinion question.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to write a homework for university about programming-paradigms.

In conclusion I can say that a good programmer should not just focus on one certain paradigm. Especially in modern oop-languages it is possible to realize different paradigms; as in Java 8 you can realize a functional paradigm with lambda-expressions, even though it is basically an imperative language.

The reason why we started thinking in paradigms is because it is easier to learn new programming-languages if you understand their underlying main-paradigm.

Furthermore I personally think it is the perfect combination of different paradigms, to get the best solution for your problem.

I think the new programming generation is essentially focused on imperative/oop-paradigm whereas programming in functional-style would be more elegant in some cases.